# How to add password to zip file on SBS 2008?

Tags: passwords, zip, windows-sbs

I'm trying to add a password to a zip file on SBS 2008, but there is no "Add Password" in the File menu.

What can I do?

Comment: You want to accomplish this using the built-in zip file support?

Comment: @DanielBeck: Yes. I can do this all the time in XP.

Comment: @CraigJ "dust in the wind" :-)  use 7zip or winrar. E-hows can be lame, but this one covers it well. http://www.ehow.com/how_8196598_put-security-zip-file.html